# Android - large TextView dyanamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I am intrested to manipulate TextView's and set them to **large** (`setTextAppearance()`) ones dynamically. (I wonder why Google always puts a snippet code for the XML not along side with the Java code).

Is anyone familiar how to do it?

**UPDATE**

```
TextView txtVw = new TextView(this);
tblRow.addView(txtVw);
txtVw.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
```

The TextView appears on screen, though it **does not appear large**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I didn't know where the ``textAppearanceLarge`` resides, so thank you for the reference. To get this working, I shall substitute ``context`` with ``this``. Right?

Comment: It didn't set the textview to a large one i.e., the textview appears on screen, though it is not **large** :(

Comment: I updated my original post. Hopefully, it'll provide more information about the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had understood. Problem is that I'm drinking beer so right now I am too drunk. Sorry, I won't answer again in this state. The edit I did should work.

Comment: THANKS ALOT!!!!!!! Any reference to the documentation which has it written? And do not apologize for your beer, though you're being drunk you are still incisive, and in this condition it just light-up your quality skills! CHEERS! :)

Comment: I have not seen that in the documentation. Android documentation sucks... you knew that already.

Answer (score 1):

this is better , put it in your textview xml declaration

```
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```